# How to find value in two columns and return matching value in corresponding columns?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

```
          A           B              C                 D
1   Distance 1  Area 1  Distance 2  Area 2
2      100        11       200        16
3      300        12       400        17
4      500        13       600        18
5      700        14       800        19
6      900        15       1000       20
```

I need formula to return area in B9 after entering distance value in A9. If I enter 300 in cell A9 then B9 should return 13. If I enter 700 in A9, then B9 should return 17. I know if distance and areas be in single column then INDEX MATCH formula can be used. But I can't set values in single columns. Please help which formula shall work? Isn't there any formula without using IF? Like INDEX(Column A & Column C(Match A9, In Column B & Column D))

Comment: Can you explain the relationship between input and output? Why does 300 >> 13 and 700 >> 17? It's not at all clear to me in this question - and I think the answers below were written before you edited your table and moved everything around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `B9`, enter formula :

```
=SUMIF(A2:C6,A9,B2:D6)
```

[image]

Comment: thanks dear. You made my day. I was thinking only of INDEX MATCH, but didn't think that SUMIF will work well as the DISTANCE columns have unique values.

Answer (score 2):

In **B9** enter:

```
=IF(A9<=500,VLOOKUP(A9,A2:B6,2),VLOOKUP(A9,C2:D6,2))
```

[image]

*(MATCH() and INDEX() can be used in a similar fashion)*

Comment: The only change I would make is the `=IF(A9<600,...` as `501` to `599` will cause an error.

Comment: @ScottCraner  **You are correct** I assumed that the input in **A9** would be an exact match to one of the table values.